# Host 2 Seperate DNS servers on one server?

Tags: dns, bind, cpanel

Just wondering if its possible to have 2 different DNS servers on a server? For instance i am running BIND DNS (Through cPanel), and wish to run a separate instance of PowerDNS as well. Is this possible? Can i do this with 1 IP? Or do i need 2? Or is it not possible to do this with a cPanel BIND?

I have not tried anything as of yet as i don't want to ruin the DNS currently in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run two DNS servers on the same IP address (as both need port `53` on that IP address). However, servers are not restricted to one IP address (multiple interfaces, interface aliasing, etc.) so you could run a different DNS server on each IP address you have as long as you tell every DNS server which IP it needs to bind to.